# Reduce horizontal space in FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: winforms

See image I want to decrease the space horizontally between each row of controls.

This Windows forms FlowLayoutPanel. I've have highlighted one cell in red to show spacing currently.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can quite easily create you own custom FlowLayoutPanel by deriving from panel.

Although the code below is setting a uniform border for both horizontal and vertical you could quite easily modify to have a property each for horizonatal and vertical spacing.

```
public class FlowPanel : Panel
{
    protected int _TileBorder;
    public int TileBorder
    {
        get
        {
            return this._TileBorder;
        }
        set
        {
            this._TileBorder = value;
            this.RearrangeControls(this, this.TileBorder);
        }
    }
    public FlowPanel()
    {
        this.AutoScroll = true;
    }
    public FlowPanel(int tileBorder)
    {
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        this.TileBorder = tileBorder;
    }
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        this.RearrangeControls(this, this.TileBorder);
    }
    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnControlAdded(e);
        this.RearrangeControls(this, this.TileBorder);
        e.Control.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(this.Control_SizeChanged);
    }
    protected override void OnControlRemoved(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnControlRemoved(e);
        this.RearrangeControls(this, this.TileBorder);
        e.Control.SizeChanged -= new EventHandler(this.Control_SizeChanged);
    }
    protected void RearrangeControls(Panel p, int border)
    {
        int num = border;
        int num2 = border;
        int num3 = 0;
        bool flag = true;
        foreach (Control control in p.Controls)
        {
            if (control != null)
            {
                num3 = ((control.Height > num3) ? control.Height : num3);
                if (flag)
                {
                    num += control.Width + border;
                    control.Location = new Point(border, border);
                    flag = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (num + control.Width + 2 * border > p.Width)
                    {
                        num2 += num3 + border;
                        control.Location = new Point(border, num2);
                        num = border + (control.Width + border);
                        num3 = control.Height;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        control.Location = new Point(num, num2);
                        num += control.Width + border;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void Control_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.RearrangeControls(this, this.TileBorder);
    }
}
```

Now that I look at it, the RearrangeControls method does look slightly hacked-together-in-a-hurry to me now, but I'm sure you could make it nicer!

Comment: The problem was inner panels that had the default height set.